# Redundant command as an affirmation of authority?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am fairly certain that there's an idiomatic phrase for this, referring to either the situation or the person. It's on the tip of my tongue.

Scenario: Alice tells Bob to stop making a such a noise with his power tools. Bob replies that he had already stopped an hour ago and was anyway done for the day.

How would you describe Alice, who instructed Bob to do something which he already did or was going to do? In other words, she gave him a redundant order that serves no purpose other than to reaffirm authority and stroke her own ego. Alternatively, she's making a show of strength by demanding that something that's already been done, be done.

It's similar in concept to the French phrase "*faire la mouche du coche*" but not quite. It's along the lines of **gadfly**, **backseat driver**, **busybody**, or **tooting one's own horn**.

EDIT: The closest matches so far are **control freak** and **megalomaniac**, but those still don't describe the post-facto aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alice is being officious.

> Assertive of authority in an annoyingly domineering way, especially with regard to petty or trivial matters.

[Lexico](https://lexico.com/definition/officious)

Comment: Yes! I think this is the closest I'm going to get. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In an attempt to reiterate her authority, or just to show who's the boss, Alice ended up ***beating a dead horse*** when she asked Bob to stop making noise with his tools (which he stopped using an hour earlier).

Wiktionary:

> *Verb*
> **[beat a dead horse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beat_a_dead_horse)**
>
> (*idiomatic*) To persist or continue far beyond any purpose, interest
> or reason.
>
> After having shown us three hours of instructional and
> safety videos, the inspector was simply beating a dead horse by
> telling us to buckle up as we got into the van.
>
> Alternative forms:
> *flog a dead horse*

Comment: I would say that's more of a side-effect of what she's doing, but that's really really close.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word **nag**

ex. "Stop **nagging** me about this, Alice" or "Alice is being such a **nag**"

Comment: Close but not quite. Nagging implies repetition, which is not what I'm looking for. Maybe I used a bad example. It's about the fact that the command was unnecessary because the action was already underway, and yet it was given anyway purely out of pride or saving face.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't think of an idiomatic phrase that rolls off the tip of the tongue but I'd still like to float the idea that Alice's behavior indicates that she is a "**pettifogger** of the first water".

**pettifogger:** (noun) One given to quibbling over trifles. (Merriam-Webster)

**...of the first water** (idiom) Used to refer to a person or thing that is unsurpassed of their kind, typically in an undesirable way. 'She was a bore of the first water.'  (Oxford Dictionary)

Comment: You're getting closer, "petty" (in the sense of a petty officer) is a good way to describe it, but still not quite on point about having an urge to micromanage unnecessarily.

Comment: @Leeward Er...OBSESSIVE pettifogger... Will that improve matters?

Comment: Better, but still doesn't reflect the futility of issuing a retroactive order for something that already happened. Like a drill sergeant

Comment: who yells "do it again" when a private finishes a task faster than the other recruits.

Comment: (Sorry for triple-posting, I hit enter by accident)

Comment: @Leeward This is getting very Alice-in-Wonderland-like. "Off with his head!"

Comment: LOL I was just using [these guys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) XD

Comment: @Leeward [This fellow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlL2W2F3nlA) could answer your question straight away.

Answer (score 0):

[*Hectoring*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hector), perhaps:

> To talk and behave towards someone in a loud and unpleasantly forceful way, especially in order to get them to act or think as you want.

Comment: That's not it either. It's not forceful, it's just annoying and laughably supercilious.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who takes pleasure in petty and unnecessary (and "redundant" implies unnecessary) displays of authority would colloquially be said to be ***throwing their weight around, power-tripping,*** or ***flexing their muscles.***

Other terms and phrases that could describe such a person include ***imperious, lordly, high-handed, bossy, controlling, domineering,*** or if the emphasis is on the pettiness, they could be said to be ***micromanaging, backseat driving,*** or ***breathing down your neck.*** Of these, *imperious, lordly,* and *high-handed* are the ones that most imply the person is enjoying the exercise of power for its own sake.